# WPF converter column ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, converters

I want to add a converter in my `DataGrid` that is binded with an itemsSource.

```
        <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding List}"/>
```

And `ItemSource` has been binded with a `list`. There is a boolean property (`IsClientGood`). I want that my datagrid doesn't show a checkbox but a color thanks to a converter. Here is the converter. Thank you guys for your help !

Answer (score 2):

I assume, that you don't know, where to place the converter?
If you want to customize the look of `DataGrid`, you must avoid generating columns from properties, ad define them manually.

Something like this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ClientList}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Is client good">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Fill="{Binding IsClientGood, Converter={StaticResource BoolToColorConverterKey}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <!-- Other columns here -->
    </DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGrid>
```

where `BoolToColorConverterKey` is a key of resource, that defines your `BoolToColor` converter.

Comment: Thanks @Dennis it works but it generates the same column IcClientGood, there are two same column the first one it with color and the other with the checkbox, how to delete one with the checkbox ? Thanks

Comment: With AutoGenerateColumns="False". I have a problem. The grid isn't show the details of the columns

Comment: You have to setup all of the columns manually. There's comment "Other columns here" - either you're using automatically generated columns with default view, or you're setting up all columns manually with custom view.